# Exporting large (> 1GB) BQ tables in AVRO format - expected multiple files of 1 GB each but only single file exported

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to export a BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage in AVRO format. The size of the table is 2.6 GB. I ran a command similar to:

```
bq extract \
--destination_format AVRO \
'mydataset.mytable' \
gs://example-bucket/myfile*.avro
```

The ***** or wildcard is required if the BigQuery table is > 1 GB and it is supposed to shard into files of 1 GB each. However, when running this I only get a single file (~2.8 GB) exported that is named: **gs://example-bucket/myfile000000000000.avro** Is this the correct behavior and the documentation just needs to be updated as per here? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Here is a screenshot showing the file size in the BQ UI:

[image: Table Size]

Running this command shows the exported file is almost 2.8 GB:

`gsutil ls -lh "gs://FOLDER_ON_GCS"`

```
2.78 GiB  2019-09-06T01:10:12Z  gs://FULL_PATH_TO_FILE.avro
TOTAL: 1 objects, 2982798742 bytes (2.78 GiB)
```

Comment: What the size of the exported file ?

Comment: My suspicion is that your table is not 2.8 GB! Have you tried without the * wildcard and was it successful? If the table is 2.8 GB and tried without the * wildcard you should get an error similar to the following "BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job... Table xxxxx too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export..." - can you validate - thanks

Comment: Yes @StéphaneFréchette it is indeed 2.8 GB and I did get the same error you mentioned. This is the query I used to find the table's file size (in python): 
        "SELECT size_bytes/pow(10,9) as size
        FROM \`DATASETNAME.{0}.__TABLES__\` 
        WHERE table_id = '{1}'".format(dataset_id, table_id)```

Comment: Any chance you want to go with a CSV format?

Comment: Thanks @Jas I not sure i like this query (python) to get the table size! Can you go to your GCP Console and to BigQuery and for your table under the Query Editor select Details and in Table Info you should see the Table size, would it be possible to post this screenshot (with Table size) by editing your Q and including it. Also if possible a screenshot of the file in GCS with the size of the file - thanks

Comment: @khan No, I need to go with AVRO for various reasons. But perhaps the splitting of files only happens with csv and JSON files.

Comment: If you want to go a bit different route, you can choose to generate these in the form of CSV files, importing them locally (`gsutil cp`) and converting into AVRO and uploading them back (`gsutil cp`). Sharding output results in BigQuery has been a bit of a dynamic process.

Comment: @khan it is nested data so the only alternative would be to use JSON, but chose not to go down that route for various reasons, namely the huge benefit of AVRO being faster and also including the schema in the file itself.

Comment: I did some tests with a public table `bigquery-public-data:ncaa_basketball.mbb_pbp_sr` and it works fine: `TOTAL: 36 objects, 3341018880 bytes (3.11 GiB)`. Can it be your table? Which `bq version` are you using (I tested with 2.0.45)? In any case it's strange that you get the error without the wildcard and then it writes to a single file. Are you sure you don't have something like a Cloud Function that composes/auto-merges the files like [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-write-to-a-single-shard-on-google-cloud-storage-efficiently-using-cloud-dataflow-and-cloud-3aeef1732325)?

Comment: You can also confirm the latter by inspecting the extract job with `bq show -j --format=prettyjson FULL_JOB_ID | grep -A 2 destinationUriFileCounts`. Also, does it work as expected with the UI?

Comment: I would say @Jas is right. I did try extracting a table sized 2.8 gigs to GCS, and it did shard into files sized ~ 550 gig/file. However, in the past, I have seen some weird sharding issues and variable number of shards (which sometimes end up as a single file, irrespective of the output format).

Comment: @GuillemXercavins ```Jass-MacBook-Air:~ $ bq version
This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.47``` No, I don't have any such function that composes into one file. I'm simply doing an export operation from bq CLI. I don't know what is special about my table other than it is Google Analytics session data which is hierarchical and I'm exporting to AVRO.

Comment: @GuillemXercavins Here is the result of this command: ```Jass-MacBook-Air:~ $ bq show -j --format=prettyjson bqjob_r2ce381d897472305_0000016d098bbd96_1 | grep -A 2 destinationUriFileCounts
      "destinationUriFileCounts": [
        "1"
      ], ```